# Retrieve URL from MVC ViewData in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Struggling with this a bit. I'm passing an absolute URL from the controller to View and trying to retrieve the URL in the jquery to pass it to an Ajax call. The URL isn't constructing right. Any help on how to retrieve it the right way?

I tried @Html.Raw here. But with no luck!

MVC Controller

```
 public IActionResult Something() 
 {
   var baseDirPath= System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
   var fileLocation = Path.Combine(baseDirPath, "wwwroot", "myDir", 
                      "test.docx");
   ViewData["Path"] = fileLocation;
   return View();
}
```

MVC View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Cannotretrieve the path here from the viewdata
        var path = "@Html.Raw(ViewData["Path"])"; 
        console.log(documentPath);

        var kkk= $("#div");
        kkk.kendoWindow({
            open: function (e) {
                $.ajax({                      
                    url: documentPath,
                    async: true,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        //success
                    },

                });
            }
        }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you show example path, what path it is ?

Comment: Updated controller code

Comment: you cannot access the file using absolute path, you need to use relative path

Comment: did you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
if your view is razor:

var str = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["Path"]));
```

or if it's web form, using the JavaScriptSerializer (and after importing     theproper namespace to your webform - System.Web.Script.Serialization):

```
var str = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["Path"])) %>;
in  MVC application. Use view models and strongly typed views so that your   code looks like this:

var str = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Path) %>;
This technique is even cooler as now you can JSON serialize the entire view     model:

var model = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
var str = model.Path;
```

Comment: Thanks sd.n. I'm using Razor. But I cannot resolve 'Encode' in Json.Encode. I'm using MVC6

Comment: @aspnetbeginner245 - MVC 6 has been renamed to MVC Core. You should add the correct tags to your question if you want relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewData.Eval()` with `Html.Encode()` in jquery

```
var path = '@Html.Encode(ViewData.Eval("Path"))';
console.log(path);
```